# Yosemite black screen with cursor after log in

Tags: macos, error, startup

Running the Macbook6,1 with Yosemite installed. I have my macbook set up so that when it powers on, it automatically logs into my account. When I boot up my macbook, it goes to the log in window and shows my desktop background all blurred (like it is meant to) and attempts to log me in. After that, the screen just goes black and my cursor remains on screen.

Comment: did you try to login in Safe mode, or as another user?

Comment: I am the only user on the laptop; I have tried using Safe mode. It gets me to the log in screen and prompts me to input my password. After doing so, it accepts the password and displays a circling pin wheel before fading to black with my cursor. Shortly after, it brings me back to the log in screen. It does the same thing when I boot normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into the recovery mode (CMD+R) and in Disk Utility repair both the disk and the disk permissions. Once done, restart the computer and see if it works properly again. :)

Comment: I repaired both multiple times, but still no luck. It did cause on change, however. After logging in and the screen goes black, it brings me back to the log in screen. Re-entering my password will just make this loop :P

Any other ideas?

Comment: To try with another user you can do the following:
1. Boot in single user mode with CMD + S
2. Type /sbin/mount -uw /
3. Type rm /var/db/.applesetupdone
4. Type restart

When you'll start the computer, it will think that the startup setup has not been done, and will ask you to configure the computer as it was new. That way you'll be able to create a new admin user and see if it's a session problem or not.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Following your instruction, I was able to create a new account and that account works almost perfectly fine (Finder seems to be a bit unstable, quitting and relaunching every 5 or so minutes, and the Macbook seems a bit slow). 

Do you reckon logging into the original account would be feasible?

Comment: Based on what you are saying, I would recommend to make a backup of all important files now that you have access to the computer and then perform a fresh restore of the system.

Comment: I was playing around in Terminal and Disk Utility. Using Terminal, I enabled the Debug menu on Disk Utility, allowing me to view all partitions on my Mac. I mounted EFI and Recovery HD, backed them, and deleted the originals. I restarted my computer, restored them and for some reason my mac is working perfectly fine now. 

Thank you for your assistance Ricard Tolosa! :)